# Yahoo.extend in alfresco for extending dnd-upload component

Tags: javascript, yui, alfresco

I would like to customize the dnd-upload.js file. For example I want to override `_adjustGuiIfFinished` method. I've tried several times to do it, but all of them failed (I was using some tutorials/examples:

- http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2011/08/12/custom-admin-console-components-in-share/
- https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/javascrip-autocompete-yahoo-library-03152012)

Here are my steps:

- create .js file, let's say `dnd-upload-ep.js` with following contents:

```js
(function ()
    {
      Alfresco.EpDNDUpload = function Alfresco_EpDNDUpload(htmlId)
      {
        Alfresco.EpDNDUpload.superclass.constructor.call(this, htmlId);
        return this;
      };

      YAHOO.extend(Alfresco.EpDNDUpload, Alfresco.DNDUpload,{
        _adjustGuiIfFinished: function EpDNDUpload_adjustGuiIfFinished()
        {
    ...
    // function body with some modifications
    ...
      })
    });
```

- include just created file in .ftl. Override `dnd-upload.get.html.ftl` and include file in js dependencies:

```xml
...
<@markup id="js">
   <#-- JavaScript Dependencies -->
  <@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/components/upload/dnd-upload.js" group="upload"/>
  <@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/components/upload/dnd-upload-ep.js" group="upload"/>
</@>
...
```

- instead of original `DNDUpload` instantiate recently created `EpDNDUpload`. To do it override `dnd-upload.get.js` changing 'Widget instantiation metadata':

```js
...
//Widget instantiation metadata...
   var dndUpload = {
      id : "EpDNDUpload",
      name : "Alfresco.EpDNDUpload",
      assignTo : "dndUpload"
   };
   model.widgets = [dndUpload];
...
```

Seems that it should work, but it doesn't. When I upload document I got error that `Alfresco.EpDNDUpload` not created and could't be instantiated.

Is there is something I do wrong?